# The group of units of $\{a+bi\sqrt{2}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is $\{1,-1\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The exercise is to show the group of units of the ring $\{a+bi\sqrt{2}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is $\{1,-1\}$. I don't understand the beginning of the book's solution:

> Suppose $a+bi\sqrt{2}$ has an inverse $x+yi\sqrt{2}$. Then $|a+bi\sqrt{2}|^{2}|x+yi\sqrt{2}|^{2}=1$. That is, $(a^{2}+2b^{2})(x^{2}+2y^{2})=1$.

First, why the absolute value instead of just $(a+bi\sqrt{2})
(x+yi\sqrt{2})=1\implies(a+bi\sqrt{2})^{2}(x+yi\sqrt{2})^{2}=1?$

Second, how did they get $(a^{2}+2b^{2})(x^{2}+2y^{2})=1?$

When I did this:
$$\begin{align}
|a+bi\sqrt{2}|^{2}|x+yi\sqrt{2}|^{2}&=|(a+bi\sqrt{2})^{2}(x+yi\sqrt{2})^{2}|\\
&=|((a^{2}-2b^{2})+2abi\sqrt{2})((c^{2}-2d^{2})+2cdi\sqrt{2})|\\
&=|(a^{2}-2b^{2})(x^{2}-2y^{2})-8abxy+\text{other stuff with }i|.
\end{align}$$

What about the $-8abxy$? Doesn't that have to be set $=1$, too?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specify which book you're using in an [edit]. The information is likely to be useful for others.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the title of the book. My school has online access so I downloaded it last year and printed the book except the cover and preface, and I can't find the title of the book on the other pages. I just dug it out to read now since it's winter break, but I'm only at the first chapter, first section of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a norm with values in $\mathbb{N}$ on that ring. It is defined by $N(a+i\sqrt{2}b)=a^2+2b^2$. This norm is multiplicative, you can check that. So if $x$ and $y$ are inverses of each other $i.e.$ $xy=1$ then $1=N(1)=N(xy)=N(x)N(y) $ which implies $N(x)=N(y)=1$. From this you get that the only invertible elements are $\pm 1$.

Comment: But $a,b$ should be integers, so only $\pm 1$ are units.

Comment: Edited! I was thinking of the Gauss integers. Sorry.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I thought $a+ib\sqrt{2}\mapsto a^{2}+2b^{2}$ might be a norm but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 3):

You are working with complex numbers here, and the absolute value of a complex number is defined by $|a+bi| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ ($a$ and $b$ being the real and imaginary parts), the length of the vector from (0,0) to $(a,b)$.

You seem to be saying that $|z|^2 = z^2$, which is incorrect; that only works with real numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about that.